# Simplify calling method on item in array_map

Tags: php, syntax

Suppose that we have a class representing an entity knowing its name:

```
class Entity
{
    private $name;
    public function __construct(string $name) { $this->name = $name; }
    public function getName() :string { return $this->name; }
}
```

and we have an array of such entities:

```
$entities = [ new Entity('Alice'), new Entity('Bob') ];
```

What we really want is array of their names, so we use `array_map` function:

```
$names = array_map(
    function($entity) { return $entity->getName(); },
    $entities
);
```

But even though I removed type hints from the closure, the syntax still looks bulky to me, especially while knowing about `[ $object, 'methodName' ]` closure syntax.

Is there a way to simplify the array_map construction?

Comment: It looks okay to me.

Comment: After getting in touch with NodeJs, it doesn't look good for me unfortunately. I'll be disappointed knowing it's indeed cannot be simplified.

Comment: I don't really know how it really works, but what's the point of duplicating names ? I mean, you have an array of objects which have name, you only want the names, so you now have an array of objects which have name and an array of name. Maybe I'm completely wrong but that seems logical to me

Comment: @Zyigh suppose some function takes array of names and does something with them

Comment: Yeah unfortunately to my knowledge arrow function syntax is still in RFC for php

Comment: @Illia Somov, then why not add a __toString method that returns the name ?

Comment: @Dimitris yup, and they have technical problems implementing it it seems (both `=>` and `->` operators are already reserved). Sad to know.

Comment: @Zyigh well, __toString may indeed work for case with name, but the entity may also have other fields for which we want to do the same thing, name was an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no shorter syntax for this. There are two RFC's (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions, https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short-closures), which want to introduce short closures, but they are still in draft and it's difficult to get a 2/3 majority for such features in php. In the near future I wouldn't expect them to apear in the language.

If you need a cleaner syntax for this case, you could create your own lambda generator.

```
function getPropertyLambda($property) {
    return function($item) use ($property) {
        return $item->{'get' . ucfirst($property)}();
    };
}

$names = array_map(getPropertyLambda("name"), $entities);
```

Comment: Interesting solution!

Answer (score 2):

What you have looks okay to me.

The only other possible solution would be using `array_column()`, but it would only work if you declare `name` as `public`:

**(PHP Version >= 7.0)**

```
<?php

class Entity
{
    public $name = 'Alice';
    public function __construct(string $name) { $this->name = $name; }
};

$entities = [ new Entity('Alice'), new Entity('Bob') ];

var_dump(array_column($entities, 'name'));
```

**Output**

> array(2) {
>
> [0]=>
>
> string(5) "Alice"
>
> [1]=>
>
> string(3) "Bob"
>
> }

https://3v4l.org/VIVPU

Comment: Didn't know array_column works for properties oO. Your solution breaks encapsulation, but nice try indeed :)